# OpenCV image processing in android

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, android

Please check out the image links and can you please suggest the best possible way to detect the ball in the image? I tried edge detection with contours, hough circles and most of the regular ways probably but I get too much background noise.

Can someone please suggest a way to detect the ball in both of the linked images?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuLa7.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/30ex9.jpg

Comment: using a ball with a unique color that gives a good contrast vs the grass would make life much easier. if this is just a frame from a video and you want to track the ball use optical flow or similar approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.
I have detected the colored object with HSV feature before.
I converted RGB image to HSV image and then detect the object with using the range of hue for the target color.

After threshold with range of hue(inrange), find contour function of OpenCV was used.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the color detection would be useful rather the shape features.
I have worked such project before, and I have solved this in HSV space.

At first, I converted the image from RGB to HSV.
And then create binary image with threshold function for target color range.
At last, located the position of object(ball) with Hough Circle detect function.

Please check follow, it would be help you, I think:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/04/opencv-python-color-detection/

Thanks.

Comment: Did you use inRange?